# Execute robotframework test with phantomJs

Tags: phantomjs, robotframework

I developed my tests with robotframework and now I want to put them in CI.
In my CI plateforme I do not have navigator, so I use phantomJs my problem is that phantoms does not open my site but it gives me white page.
I use this code to open my site

```
Open Browser    ${myURL}    phantomjs
```

I do some research and I found this link https://github.com/pa11y/pa11y/issues/90 that propose to try opening the site with curl. The execution of curl returns

```
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
the -k (or --insecure) option.
```

So I launch my phantomJs with  the commande `phantomjs --ignore-ssl-errors=true --ssl-protocol=any --webdriver=8010` but I still have the same problem any help please.

Comment: Which PhantomJS version do you use? Have you tried to add `--web-security=false` as a commandline option for PhantomJS?

Comment: I have phantomJs 2.1.1, yes I tried that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved my issue by launching phantomJs with the commande

```
phantomjs --ignore-ssl-errors=true --ssl-protocol=any --webdriver=8010
```

and changing my test to

```
${desired capabilities}=    Evaluate    {'phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36'}

Open Browser    ${URL}  phantomjs   main browser    http://localhost:8010   desired_capabilities=${desired capabilities}
```

I found the response on http://spage.fi/phantomjs

I hope that can help some one.